# Parsing xml File with elisp

Tags: xml, parsing, elisp

I have a xml file with this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<trials>

<trial>
    <main>
        <trial_id>RBR-3ypfxv</trial_id>
        <utrn>U1111-1191-5058</utrn>
        <reg_name>REBEC</reg_name>
        <date_registration>04/05/2017</date_registration>
        <primary_sponsor>Faculdade de Medicina da Univesidade de São Paulo - São Paulo, SP, Brazil</primary_sponsor>
        <public_title>Effectiveness of Intragastric balloon associated with diet on treatment of patients with type 2 diabetes </public_title>
        <acronym></acronym>
        <scientific_title>Evaluation of Intragastric Balloon effectiveness associated to diet on treatment of diabetic patients with BMI&lt;35 </scientific_title>
    </main>
</trial>

</trials>
```

And I need to get the values of:

- `trial_id`
- `scientific_title`

into a list.

How can i load this file and return those values?

i used:

```
(defun load-xml-ictrp (filePath)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents filePath)))

(let ((str "<trial_id>RBR-3ypfxv</trial_id>"))
  (string-match "<trial_id>(.*?)</trial_id>" str)
  (match-strings-all str))
```

but this last block returns `">RBR-3y"` and i was expecting `"RBR-3ypfxv"`.

Answer (score 4):

Emacs comes with [`xml.el`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/xml.el) which is all you need:

```
(require 'xml)
(setq parse-tree (xml-parse-file "test.xml"))    
(setq trials-node (assq 'trials parse-tree))
(setq trial-node (car (xml-get-children trials-node 'trial)))
(setq main-node (car (xml-get-children trial-node 'main)))
(setq trial_id-node (car (xml-get-children main-node 'trial_id)))
(car (xml-node-children trial_id-node))
==> "RBR-3ypfxv"
(setq scientific_title-node (car (xml-get-children main-node 'scientific_title)))
(car (xml-node-children scientific_title-node))
==> "Evaluation of Intragastric Balloon effectiveness associated to diet on treatment of diabetic patients with BMI<35 "
```

**Notes:**

- `xml-get-children` returns the list of nodes with the given name, so you need to use `car` to get the first one.
  You might also want to check that it is the *only* one.
- `xml-node-children` returns the list of all children, so you need to use `car` to get the first one.
  You might also want to check that there is *only* one child.
- It would be a good idea for you to examine the values of the variables I create above, as well as the definitions of the functions I use...

Comment: thanks!  is it possible create a function to lopp over the xml-get-children:

like this:  (defun get-mail (list-contact)
  (setq email-node (car (xml-get-children list-contact 'email)))
  (setq list-contact (cdr list-contact))
  (get-mail list-contact)
)

Comment: @dtostes: your function is broken in many ways, you should ask a separate question.